# imprimir tabla de cuadrados en Java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> El 6 de mayo de 1949, Maurice Wilkes creó el primer programa
>   almacenado en una máquina lo suficientemente potente para realizar
>   cálculos matemáticos de forma práctica. Esta máquina, llamada EDSAC,
>   calculó e imprimió la tabla de cuadrados de los primeros 100 números
>   (0-99) mostrada a continuación:
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> Haz un programa que genere la misma salida que el programa de Wilkes.

Consigo hacer el bucle de los cuadrados y demás pero no sé cómo hacer la impresión para que se muestre como pide.

```
    public class tarea6 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int i = 1, cuad = 0, n1 = 1, sum = 0;
            for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
                cuad = n1 * i;
                cuad = cuad * i;
                sum = sum + cuad;

                System.out.printf("%05d \n", cuad);         
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Abajo tienes una respuesta que soluciona tu problema, pero en ambos casos, en el tuyo y en la respuesta, para empezar en 0 y terminar en 99, el bucle for debería ser desde i = 0 hasta que i < 100. Sino, el primer cuadrado será el del 1 y no el del 0, y el último sería el del 100 y no el del 99.

Comment: "*Haz un programa que genere la misma salida que el programa de Wilkes*". ¿Cómo que **Haz un programa**? ¡Se te olvidó decir "por favor"!

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster eso dice su ejercicio ...

Comment: @UselesssCat ¿El enunciado del ejercicio tiene algo que ver con el problema que tiene?

Answer (score 7):

Tienes un enredo en el ciclo for, yo lo haria asi:

```
public class tarea6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int cuad = i * i;
            System.out.printf("%04d ", cuad); //4 dígitos y un espacio
            if(i % 10 == 9) {
                System.out.println(); //salto de línea cada 10 números
            }             
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Casi lo tenías, lo he arreglado un poco para dar el resultado exacto y mantiendo la ida original del OP

Comment: Execlente el arreglo Pablo Lozano

Answer (score 0):

Puedes imprimir este texto de una manera simple usando Streams:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      IntStream.range(0, 100)
          .forEach(s -> System.out.printf("%04d%s", s * s, s % 10 == 9 ? "\n": " "));
  }
}
```

Comment: Genial, economía de código en su máxima expresión.